# Speeding up counting of tuples

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, counting

For a project I am doing I am interested in creating a list of all tuples *(i,j,k,z,f)* that fit the following criteria:

- all five variables can vary from 0 to 343
- i==k *or* j==z *or* k==f

What I have come up with so far is this:

```
z1=set()
for i in xrange(344):
    for j in xrange(344):
        for k in xrange(344):
            for z in xrange(344):
                for f in xrange(344):
                    if f!=k:
                        continue
                    z1.add((i,j,k,z,f))
for i in xrange(344):
    for j in xrange(344):
        for k in xrange(344):
            for z in xrange(344):
                for f in xrange(344):
                    if z!=j:
                        continue
                    if (i,j,k,z,f) not in z1:
                        z1.add((i,j,k,z,f))
for i in xrange(344):
    for j in xrange(344):
        for k in xrange(344):
            for z in xrange(344):
                for f in xrange(344):
                    if k!=i:
                        continue
                    if (i,j,k,z,f) not in z1:
                        z1.add((i,j,k,z,f))
```

This is very slow. I am thinking there might be an easy way to speed this up that I am overlooking... any thoughts?

Comment: Your question title refers to "counting of tuples", but your code tries to materialize a big list.  Which do you really need to do?

Comment: I want a list of tuples

Comment: Might want to consider wanting something else, then. :^)

Answer (score 4):

You need more memory. Lots and lots of memory. Let's just look at the first condition, `i == k`. The number of tuples satisfying that condition is `343 ** 4 = 13841287201`. 13 billion! If each tuple only needs `5*4 = 20` bytes of memory, that's still 257 GB which is needed for the set. And that's not even all elements of the set you desire.

So, nope, there is no easy way out. If I were to optimize this problem down to a manageable size, I'd first ask mysqlf: Do I *really* need a list that big? Or can I solve this problem without it?

Answer (score 2):

May you want to loop less and compare less.

Try the following, it might be faster:

```
def doit ():
    theRange = range (343)
    for i in theRange:
        for j in theRange:
            for k in theRange:
                cond1 = i == k
                for z in theRange:
                    cond2 = j == z
                    for f in theRange:
                        if cond1 or cond2 or k == f:
                            yield i, j, k, z, f

for x in doit ():
    doSomethingWith (x)
```

Comment: this doesn't work. i'm a little confused by exactly why it doesn't but for instance if you count the tuples this way for range(5) you get 25, but if you do it my way with only one condition per big loop you get 1525.

Comment: @adamlevin On both py2 and py3 this snippet with limit 5, produces 1525 values.

Comment: @adamlevin python 2.7.5+ and python3.2.4 to be precise.

Comment: you're right it does produce 1525, but they don't seem to be match the ones created with my code. i could be making a mistake. let me look at the other responses and i'll come back.

Comment: @adamlevin Your order is different, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

You dont really need conditions to do this,

Take advantage of sets only holding one of each value.

```
a = set()
for index in xrange(344):
    for i in xrange(344):
        for j in xrange(344):
            for k in xrange(344):
                #i==k
                a.add((index,i,index,j,k))
                #j==z
                a.add((i,index,j,index,k))
                #k==f
                a.add((i,j,index,k,index))
```

**EDIT** changed *value type* to *value* ~ I need more coffee

Answer (score 1):

Since you'll run out of memory trying to construct the set, use a generator to iterate over them without storing them all:

```
itertools.ifilter(
    lambda x: x[0] == x[2] or x[1] == x[3] or x[2] == x[4],
    itertools.product(xrange(344), repeat=5)
)
```

Of course it will still take a long time to iterate, since there is a lot to do (about 5 trillion values). More on that later.

If you *really* need this set for some peculiar reason, you could build on this idea to define a "lazy" immutable set. In Python 2:

```
class MyCollection(collections.Set):
    def __contains__(self, x):
        if not isinstance(x, tuple): return False
        if not len(x) == 5: return False
        if not all(isinstance(y, int) for y in x): return False
        if not all(0 <= y <= 343 for y in x): return False
        return self.match(x)
    @classmethod
    def match(cls, x):
        return (x[0] == x[2] or x[1] == x[3] or x[2] == x[4])
    def __iter__(self):
        return itertools.ifilter(
            self.match,
            itertools.product(xrange(344), repeat=5)
        )
    def __len__(self):
        # um. Left as an exercise for the reader. About 39 billion or so.

z1 = MyCollection()
```

You could also make the iteration somewhat more efficient by thinking of ways to avoid visiting every combination. The simplest I can think of is that if `i!=k` and `j!=z`, then the only possible value of `f` is `k`. So in that case don't iterate over all possible `f`, just output the one that will work.

However, the most efficient is probably:

- iterate over all combinations of 4 values
- you have one more value to add. This will either be tagged on the end as `f` (in which case it's equal to `k`) or else inserted into the middle as `z` or `k` (and equal to `i` or `j`).

There are 42 billion of these, but this does contain some duplicates. I don't think it's quite so simple to exclude them, but the way I'd go about it is to think of all the correct 4-tuples in order from `(0,0,0,0)` to `(344,344,344,344)`. Before outputting one of the three 5-tuples generated from each 4-tuple, decide whether any earlier 4-tuple can have generated it. If so then skip it.

Answer (score 1):

A slight tweak to @Hyboreus's code:

```
def legal_tuples():
    r = range(344)
    for i in r:
        for j in r:
            for k in r:
                i_eq_k = i == k
                for z in r:
                    if i_eq_k or j == z:
                        for f in r:
                            yield i,j,k,z,f
                    else:
                        yield i,j,k,z,k
```

Comment: +1 Maybe you want parentheses after the func definition.

Comment: I think the `list(range(344))` is not necessary even in py3 as you always start fresh iterations.

Comment: Haha. I had the same suspicion with my code, and I have just learnt this detail by... try and no error.